# Make a div with absolute position fixed onscroll of window

Tags: css, html

Hello, I have a div with properties :

```
.virtual_Drop_Down_Class{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width: 120px;
        z-index: 300;
        overflow: auto;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
```

This div will be shown as a pop up and works fine.However if the pop up is not closed and horizontal scroll is moved this div moves horizontally and is visible. I want this div to be present in the position it was poped up. Pls help.

NOTE: On vertical scroll the position remains same and works fine.

Comment: i think `position:fixed;` will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.virtual_Drop_Down_Class{
    position: fixed;}
```

use position:fixed instead of absolute

Comment: That doesnt help.Have tried all options of position attribute.The div is present in a table. I dont see any reason for which the div moves when the window is scrolled.

Comment: It will help if you can say what exactly is fiddle. Google search for fiddle is not that helpful.